# Find a UMP test in exponential family - first stage

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Consider the exponential family $f(x;\theta) = c(\theta)\exp\{b(\theta) T(x))\}h(x)$ and I would like to find a UMP test for

$$H_0: \theta \leq 0\quad \hbox{vs}\quad H_1: \theta > 0.$$

It is madotory in all books: Two steps. First, we fix $\theta_0 = 0$ and take $\theta_1 > \theta_0 = 0$. That is, first we have to find a test $\phi$ for

\begin{equation}
H_0: \theta = 0\quad \hbox{vs}\quad H_1: \theta = \theta_1 \quad \quad (1)
\end{equation}

and we have to show that $\phi$ does not depend on $\theta_1$. This the first step and I do not to describe the second step beacause I don't have problems with its procedure.

For the  hypothesis test $(1)$, by Neyman–Pearson theorem, there is some $k>0$ such that

$$\phi(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : f(x;0)k  < f(x;\theta_1)  \\
    0 & : f(x;0)k  > f(x;\theta_1)
  \end{array}
\right.$$

$$E[\phi(X)] = 0.01$$

is a UMP teste with size $0.01$. But, we can do

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f(x;0)k  < f(x;\theta_1) & \Longleftrightarrow k< \frac{c(\theta_1)}{c(0)}\exp\{T(x) (b(\theta_1) - b(0))\}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow T(x)> \frac{\ln(k\frac{c(0)}{c(\theta_1)})}{(b(\theta_1) - b(0))}:= \tilde{k}(\theta_1,k)\\
& \Longleftrightarrow T(x)>  \tilde{k}(\theta_1,k)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

And

$$E[\phi(X)] = 0.01 \implies \tilde{k}(\theta_1,k) = F^{-1}_{T}(0.99 | \theta = 0) = q_0(0.99)$$

That is $\tilde{k}(\theta_1,k)$ depends only on the null hypothesis $\theta_0 = 0$ and $0.99$. In other words, $\tilde{k}(\theta_1,k)$ is constan in the first stage. If I look at the test with this expression:

$$\phi(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : T(x) > q_0 (\theta, 0.99) \\
    0 & : T(x) < q_0 (\theta, 0.99)
  \end{array}
\right.$$

I can fully understand that this test does not depend on $\theta_1$, because $q_0 (\theta, 0.99)$ has nothing to do with $\theta_1$. But looking at this,

$$ \frac{\ln(k\frac{c(0)}{c(\theta_1)})}{(b(\theta_1) - b(0))} = q (\theta, 0.99) $$

I can not understand how I can keep $k$ fixed so that if I change $\theta_1$ by $\theta_1^{'}$ I still have exactly the same test $\phi(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : f(x;0)k  < f(x;\theta_1^{'})  \\
    0 & : f(x;0)k  > f(x;\theta_1^{'})
  \end{array}
\right.$  In the sense of being exactly equal to $\phi(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    1 & : f(x;0)k  < f(x;\theta_1)  \\
    0 & : f(x;0)k  > f(x;\theta_1)
  \end{array}
\right.$

Since if I really want to state that this test does not depend on $\theta_1> 0$, I have to keep $k$ fixed, in case I want to change to a $ \theta_{1}^{'}> 0 $. Am I confusing the true meaning of the expression "The test will not depend on $ \theta_1>0$?